# Can a sql job using a DTS package access data from the wrong column? (turned out to be bad join condition)

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, ssms

We are seeing a Sql job  / DTS package fail because it is fed non-numeric character data into an int conversion routine.

The data looks like with very high probability that it comes from another column in our tables, where its non-numeric format is appropriate.

This has occurred more than once.

Has anyone heard of a Sql job / DTS package "losing its way" and accessing data from the wrong column?

I would consider this a rare possibility, but we are using a SSMS 2008 R2 system for DTS packages (which even in that system are considered out-of-date) and I suppose anything is possible....

Comment: I suggest rewriting your question title to give more accurate context.  You are not asking about SQL jobs in general.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears (at least in this case) that the column was being accessed normally in a join clause.

It was somewhat similar to doing:

a.height = b.weight

Furthermore, imagine that weight is a double whereas height is given as a rounded inches int, and that somehow an int is expected in weight ...

while this wasn't the exact situation (it really tried to convert a char to int) it somewhat approximates it...

Apparently, surrounding logic kept this clause from actually running most of the time, hence the error which would otherwise have been quite obvious was hidden.

A colleague found it.

Still, this may help someone else......